# Move a camera inside a GLTF exported with blender using ThreeJS

Tags: three.js, blender, react-three-fiber, gltf

I'm working with game dev. He has implemented all the boardgame using Blender. He also added some sprites inside directly and linked the sprite to the Camera inside Blender so that when this camera moves, all the sprites will move accordingly to always face the Camera.

Now my question is, how can I implement this using react-three-js. I see that I can export the Camera object from blender (after exporting the GLTF with the Camera inside) and see it in my GLTF in threejs (under `gltf.cameras[0]`)

My question is, How can I change the camera position of the GLTF (not a copy in threejs) so that I can keep the rules he added for the sprite to always face the camera?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any constraints created in Blender will not be included when exporting files to other formats. Those would need to be recreated in three.js. In this case I'd recommend using [gltfjsx](https://github.com/pmndrs/gltfjsx) to create a JSX representation of your model, and then using the [<Billboard />](https://github.com/pmndrs/drei#billboard) component to keep objects facing the camera.

If you have many (100+) sprites, it may be necessary to export them as points, and then assign a [THREE.PointsMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=point#api/en/materials/PointsMaterial) that applies whatever appearance you need with a texture. Those points will face the camera automatically, as shown in [this example](https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_points_billboards).

Comment: Thank you for expanding your answer and propose billboard and pointsmaterial, I was not aware of this. I'm currently using directly the sprite component.

Comment: @DonMcurdy BillBoard put all my assets on the same line and break their position, would you know why?

Comment: It's not supposed to do that, anyway. :) It may be a problem with your JSX edits, or a bug in the Billboard component. May be easiest to go to the discord server (link at bottom of page: https://pmnd.rs/) and share your work in progress for help on that.

Comment: I'll do that, anyway thank you for the help!